# Vue js Vue-cli performing "npm run build", compiles css for image opacity to 1%

Tags: vue.js, npm

when I perform `npm run serve` everything work as intended.

when I perform `npm run build` there is "no error".

when I loot at the website the images can't be seen, then I inspect element I see the image opacity in my gallery section changes to 1%.

[image]

this is my template code:

```
<div class="gallery container">
  <div
    class="images"
    v-for="(image, index) in images"
    :key="index"
  >
    <img :src="image.small" @click="selectImage(index)" />
  </div>
</div>
```

My scss code:

```
 <style lang="scss" scoped>
    .gallery-wrapper {
      padding: 3rem 0;
      .gallery {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
        align-items: center;
        .images {
          display: flex;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
          img {
            height: auto;
            cursor: pointer;
            width: 100%;
            opacity: 85%;
            border: 5px solid aliceblue;
            &:hover {
              opacity: 100%;
              transition: 0.5s;
              border: none;
              margin: 5px 0;
              box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.62);
              width: 90%;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    </style>
```

other images are working fine. only the gallery images changes opacity when performing `npm run build`.

I look at the dist folder it generated a class with 1% opacity.

build result dist/css/app.ae40bac8.css:

```
 .gallery-wrapper .gallery .images img[data-v-c5a51ec0] {
  height: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1%;
  border: 5px solid #f0f8ff;
}
.gallery-wrapper .gallery .images img[data-v-c5a51ec0]:hover {
  opacity: 1%;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
  border: none;
  margin: 5px 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.62);
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.62);
  width: 90%;
}
```

it seems the webpack generated the wrong opacity.

Comment: The CSS inspector should show you where the `opacity` override is coming from

Comment: I did that, it is not because it was override. the compiled css file, result of "npm run build". itself is 1% opacity;

Comment: Cool, thanks for clarifying. Wouldn't really be Webpack but more likely something in node-sass / sass-loader. Try using `opacity: 0.85` and `opacity: 1` instead of percentages

Comment: It's interesting that only the `img` part has the scoped data attribute. Where is your _"scss code"_? Which of your components has a `<style scoped>` block and what is in it?

Comment: YES!!! thank you sir. so percentages %  in sass is the problem.

Comment: Well, they shouldn't be. They don't appear to be affecting your `width` properties for instance. I've tried searching the `node-sass` and `libsass` issues lists but couldn't find any existing bugs

Comment: I can't reproduce this at https://www.sassmeister.com/. What Sass compiler are you using and what version? What version of sass-loader?

Comment: I tried adding opacity with 'percentage' to my other elements like opacity 50% to 'buttons' and its compiling to 1%. but when I use 0.50 it worked. the problem occures when I use percentage.

Comment: in my package.json  "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",

Comment: And the sass compiler and version?

Comment: "sass": "^1.23.7",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",     "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"

Comment: Try `node-sass` instead of `sass`

Comment: even with node-sass. 85% still not working. but 0.85 will.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, only happens for production builds.  Insane.

Answer (score 10):

Something that worked for me is using 0.85 instead of 85%